# Howto disable comment moderation emails for admins, but not for authors

Tags: multisite, email, notifications

I'm the admin of a WordPress multisite installation, and in most of the blogs I'm the person who created the blog in the first place, and therefore my email is the admin email address.

Because of this, I get all the comment moderation emails, which I'm able to filter with some email rules.

But I wanted to disable this mails in WordPress itself – with no success.

I'm aware of the option in `Settings -> Discussion -> Email me whenever [x] Anyone posts a comment`. So I tried to disable this option, but then the regular authors of posts do not get notified, which is a *no go*.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is it even possible in WordPress to **disable** admin email notifications while still sending notifications to post authors?

Answer (score 2):

you can make a plugin out of the following code that removes an email from the recipients list and network activate it

```
function wpse158530_filter_emails($emails,$cid) {

  if (count($emails) > 1) { // you don't want to remove yourself if you are the author as well as admin
  // based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252880/remove-value-from-array-in-php
    if(($key = array_search(your email address, $emails)) !== false) {
      unset($emails[$key]);
    }
  }

  return $emails;
}

add_filter('comment_moderation_recipients','wpse158530_filter_emails',10,2);
```